# Google Cloud Function RTDB Trigger Path

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Does anyone familiar with Google Cloud functions triggered by RTDB know the best way to view an existing functions trigger path? The issue I have is when I go to copy a function (one version for dev, another for production) it doesn't copy the trigger path, and some of my triggers I can't remember the full path.

Anyone know how I can either: a)preserve the trigger path when copying a function or b)look up the full trigger path on the original function? Also need help with the trigger type (create, update, write)

Thanks All!

Comment: I'm not sure to understand properly, you create the CF directly in GCP and can't remember the exact path? Your function is not deployed as code, it's only deployed via the GCP interface?

Comment: Thats correct, I created the CF in the google cloud console, not via script and then uploading. Some of the functions I'm ready to now copy to production (the only diff is the database it targets) but it was a long time ago that I created the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the gcloud CLI, you should use the command

```
gcloud functions describe yourFunctionName --region=regionName
```

The output of this command will include `eventTrigger.resource` which is the path of the trigger and `eventTrigger.eventType` which is the trigger type.

Comment: Hooray! I also realized I could add a console.log(event) and console.log(context) to get the same information, but your method is faster for checking multiple functions.